# Why does .NET WebBrowser DocumentCompleted fire too many times for microsoft.com?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I was trying to use the .NET WebBrowser control and ran into a common problem - how do I tell when a page is really loaded completely? I looked here, and I looked on Google, and I found numerous examples and questions, and so I tried them. And the first place I tried to navigate was http://www.microsoft.com. It didn't go so well.

My code is below. I tried two different approaches - one that used the Url comparison, and one that counted frames. Neither worked as I expected... I got "Form1 - Done - Done - Done - Done" in the Text value, meaning that the page somehow completed several times.

Is there a better, more reliable method to use with complicated web pages?

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebBrowserCompleted
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Uri navTarget = new Uri(@"http://www.microsoft.com");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //webBrowser1.Navigate(navTarget);
            startNavigate(@"http://www.microsoft.com");
        }

        private int mFrameCount;

        private void startNavigate(string url)
        {
            mFrameCount = 0;
            webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
        }

        private void DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            mFrameCount += 1;
            bool done = true;
            if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
            {
                HtmlWindow win = webBrowser1.Document.Window;
                if (win.Frames.Count > mFrameCount && win.Frames.Count > 0) 
                    done = false;
            }
            if (done)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Now it is really done");
                this.Text = this.Text + " - Done";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue... I threw this code in the beginning of the `DocumentCompleted` event, to reduce the firings.

It reduced the problem greatly, but it still isn't necessarily perfect for 100% of sites.

Code:

```
If Me.wbDebugMain.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```